# Oxyplot is throwing invalid operation exception while trying to invalidate the graph

Tags: windows, exception, plot, graph, oxyplot

I'm using Oxyplot library to draw graphs in my application.

My plot model instance contains list of line series and is plotted against time on Y-axis. My application gets real time data every few seconds and this data needs to be updated on graph. So every few seconds graph is updated and invalidateplot(true) is called.

It seems to be working fine for few minutes. After that Invalidating plot is throwing the below exception constantly.

```
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource 
   resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNextRare()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at OxyPlot.ReflectionExtensions.AddRange(List`1 target, IEnumerable itemsSource, String dataFieldX, String dataFieldY) in
    oxyplot\Source\OxyPlot\Utilities\ReflectionExtensions.cs:line 89
```

I have referred to the documentations and added the invalidateplot in a synchronized block inorder to fix the issue but it didn't help.

```
  lock (MyModel.SyncRoot)
    {
      if (MyModel != null)
            MyModel.InvalidatePlot(true);
     }
```

How to fix this issue?